# Development environment and "production" environment domains

Tags: images, domain

I'm developing on a Mac, and have a domain something like:

`http://localhost/~user/foobar`

My (temp) live environment is on my domain, and the domain ends up as:

`http://example.com/foobar`, or `http://localhost/foobar`

This is only temporary because my client will eventually purchase a domain which will end up being `http://foobardomain.com` and I'll have to migrate everything there.

I am using [database sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/database-sync/) to sync my databases which is working out quite nicely so far (until now I suppose).

I've gotten a good bit of work done and have started uploading images through the wordpress UI only to find out that the full paths are saved in the database in the `wp_posts` table. This is obviously a problem because the domains are quite different and the images won't load either on the live or development site. I can run queries like:

```
UPDATE wp_posts set post_content=REPLACE(post_content, 'http://localhost/~user/foobar', 'http://example.com/foobar')
```

My questions are:

1. Is the `wp_posts.wp_content` column *the only* column I need to worry about?
2. Is it possible for wordpress to grab the images via relative URLs?
3. Is there a better solution that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to change URLs in theme options, which include options that set the URLs of header images, and URLs in widget data, as well as URLs in plugin options. Some of these URLs are relative, but many are absolute.

Best thing to do is use a tool that finds/replaces URLs all through the database and correctly deserializes/reserializes php data, such as [WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool.](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Some themes do not correctly serialize data, so sometimes a theme will lose all option and widget data when using the tool above. But this is a fault with the theme. All themes that I have come across in the WordPress directory, as well as from reputable companies such as StudioPress, correctly handle serialized php data, and there are no issues with theme data.

And some plugins - such as backup and security plugins - read the full server path when being activated - such as `/server1/home/username/public_html/wp-content/plugins/aplugin/` - and those plugins will need to be reset manually on the new host. But usually, those plugins aren't active anyway until the site is live.

See [WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

And for a full reference, see [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

If you do want to use MySQL queries as you mention in your question, you also need to change GUID's and postmeta in addition to the query you have already used:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.olddomain.com/','http://www.newdomain.com/');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://www.olddomain.com/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/');
```

Comment: As far as themes I'm creating my own. Thanks for the info, this will be helpful.

Comment: Your link is broken. I suspect you mean `https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/`

Comment: This tool is awesome. I had no idea it existed. Thanks, should make these migrations a lot easier!